# Maximum Subarray Problem - Analyzing best case, worst case, and average case time complexity big o

Tags: algorithms, polynomial-time, big-o-notation, notation

New to the board, if this is the wrong section I apologize and I will delete it. Will be helpful to be provided correct exchange to guide me through this process of learning.

If you have a given an array such as `A[1...n]` of numeric values (can be positive, zero, and negative) how may you determine the `subarray A[i...j] (1≤ i ≤ j ≤ n)` where the sum of elements is maximum overall (subvectors). Regarding the brute force algorithm below, how do you go about analyzing its best case, worst case, and average-case time complexity in terms of a polynomial of n and the asymptotic notation of ɵ. How would you even show steps? Without building out the algorithm?

Thanks in advance.

```
// PSEUDOCODE
// BRUTE-FORCE-FIND-MAXIMUM-SUBARRAY(A)
n = A.length
max-sum = -∞
for l = 1 to n
    sum = 0
    for h = l to n
        sum = sum + A[h]
        if sum > max-sum
            max-sum = sum
            low = l
            high = h
return (low, high) # No, return of MAX-HIGH
```

Note: New to the forum, not sure if this is the correct exchange. But I am referring to and referencing problems from [https://walkccc.me/CLRS/Chap04/4.1/.](https://walkccc.me/CLRS/Chap04/4.1/)

Comment: (There are recommendations about names. Such as not using small L in a context where "Arabic" 1 may feature, or I with unary/Roman.)

Comment: (I have taken the information hyperlinked *not* to be simply pirated.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your algorithm goes over all pairs $(\ell,h)$ of indices such that $1 \leq \ell \leq h \leq n$, and for each of them, runs $\Theta(1)$ operations (the rest of the steps are insignificant from an asymptotic point of view). If there are $M$ such pairs, then the best case, worst case, average case complexity are all equal to $\Theta(M)$.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer.